# home electrical not working as it should

Tags: basement, renovation

I have a 115 volt 20 amp breaker but at the plug its only showing 79 volts what can the issue be? I changed the breaker and checked the voltage at the panel

Comment: And when you checked the voltage at the panel, it was...? What happens if you plug in an incandescent (old-style, filament) light to this outlet?

Comment: Try plugging a night light, cell phone charger or other tiny load in, and check the voltage again.  I bet it goes away, and acts like you would expect.